# Where to start with FastCGI and C++

Tags: c++, apache, fastcgi

Anyone have any links or resource regarding writing a proper C++ FastCGI application?  (on top of Apache using mod_fastcgi or mod_fcgid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious one would be the [FastCGI Development Kit](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5) (for C/C++).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you [fastcgi++](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/), which is an alternative to the FDK.

It is much more easy to use and is in a C++ way.