# Is there a simple way to make a fastcgi application?

Tags: c++, fastcgi

I was wondering is there a simple way to make a fastcgi application? One that is written in C++ which can be used with nginx (or another server) to serve dynamic content quickly?

What would be required in doing something like this? Is there some kind of template or lib available which gives me an interface with fastcgi written in C (or C++)? I would like the general idea of what might be involved i dont think i'll make something like this thus i dont need details

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805487/where-to-start-with-fastcgi-and-c

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are templates or not. It's what I do, and really there's not much to it. When the user accesses your cgi from a URL, you will come into main( ) with the part of the URL following the ? in QUERY_STRING if it's a GET; and with post data on stdin if it's a POST.

You deliver the resulting web page on stdout.

There are a few nitty details, but in general it's easy as pie. Here's a [**two-page overview**](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-devel-kit.htm#S4)

Comment: That sounds ridiculously easy. I imagine setting http status code just plainly writing the header with 2 new lines before the body. Ok but what about simultaneous request? shouldnt main be for the start of the instance so i can set things up that have nothing to do with request/pages? also are you talking about cgi or fastcgi?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot about the headers and you are exactly right. A simultaneous request in cgi loads a new instance of your cgi program. Not sure if it's the same in fastcgi. I am not running fastcgi yet.

Comment: You have described CGI, not FASTCGI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the protocol itself, you could use SCGI, not FastCgi. SCGI is simpler to parse (but perhaps less efficient).

You could code your application using other languages than C++ (think of [OPA](http://opalang.org) or of [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr) with [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org)).

If you insist on using C++, you might use some web related libraries, like [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/)

If you accept generated C++, you might consider [Kaya](http://kayalang.org)

Answer (score 0):

> The obvious one would be the [FastCGI Development Kit](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5) (for C/C++).

[Where to start with FastCGI and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805487/where-to-start-with-fastcgi-and-c/805799#805799)